# ¿Llamar a funciones dinamicas desde funcion estatica?

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy teniendo un problema muy tonto, y no se que mas vueltas darle, he probado creando instancias pero algo estará mal.

Tengo una función static que recoge el valor de una ventana externa, y depende del valor de esa función, necesito que llame a otras funciones.

---

`TareaView.h`

```
class PLUGIN_TAR_EXPORT TareaView
      : public BlForm
      , public Ui::TareaBase
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   TareaView(BlMainCompany *, QWidget *);
  ...

   static void recogerValor(QString);
   void avisarAsignado();

....
}
```

---

`TareaView.cpp` (función estática)

```
void TareaView::recogerValor(QString v){

    if(v==""){
        g_s->msgError("Nada seleccionado");
        avisarAsignado();
    }
    if(v=="0"){
        g_s->msgError("Madera");
    }
    if(v=="1"){
        g_s->msgError("Metaclilato");
    }
    if(v=="2"){
        g_s->msgError("Ambos");
    }
}
```

(función dinámica)

```
void TareaView::avisarAsignado(){

    m_enviando_email_al_asignado = true;
    QString nombre_from = mui_list->dbValue("empleado_solicitante");
    QString email_from = mui_list->dbValue("email_empleado_solicitante");
    QStringList nombres_to;
    QStringList emails_to;
    QString id_empleado_asignado = mui_list->dbValue("id_empleado");

    avisar(nombre_from, email_from, nombres_to, emails_to);

}
```

---

ERROR:

> ```
> tareaview.cpp. error: cannot call member function ‘void TareaView::avisarAsignado()’ without object
>      avisarAsignado();
> ```

---

Siguiendo [tus recomendaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/192714/2742), no he conseguido solucionar el problema.

Ya que no se exactamente donde ni cómo crear la instancia. Yo a traves una funcion estatica "recogerValor" que se encuentra en TareaView.cpp recojo el valor del numero de checkboxs seleccionados En TareaViewEquipo, y con la acción del boton aceptar de la ventana, le paso el valor recogido a "recogerValor" de Tareaview.

Desde TareaView, llamo a la ventana asi:

```
TareaViewEquipo *bud = new TareaViewEquipo((BlMainCompany *) mainCompany(), this); 
bud->show();
```

Se abre la ventana, seleciono los checkboxs, y al pulsar en aceptar, antes del close(), mando el valor a TareaView de la siguiente manera, a la función estatica.

```
TareaView::recogerValor(QString(valor),TareaView &tv);
```

Y ahora me dice:

> ```
> tareaview.cpp:998: error: prototype for ‘void TareaView::recogerValor(QString, TareaView&)’ does not match any in class ‘TareaView’ void TareaView::recogerValor(QString v, TareaView &tv){ ^
> ```

Y:

> ```
> tareaview.h:117: error: candidate is: static void TareaView::recogerValor(QString, TareaView)
> static void recogerValor(QString, TareaView);
>             ^
> ```

---

Adjunto Funciones:

`TareaView.h`

```
class PLUGIN_TAR_EXPORT TareaView
      : public BlForm
      , public Ui::TareaBase
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   TareaView(BlMainCompany *, QWidget *);

   static void recogerValor(QString, TareaView);
   void avisarAsignado();
...

protected:
...
```

`TareaView.cpp` Donde llamo a la ventana:

```
TareaViewEquipo *bud = new TareaViewEquipo((BlMainCompany *) mainCompany(), this);
        bud->show();
```

---

`TareaViewEquipo.cpp` (ventana)

```
void TareaViewEquipo::on_mui_aceptar_clicked()
{
    QString valor;
    valor=pasarvalor();
    TareaView::recogerValor(QString(valor));
    close();
}
```

---

`TareaView.cpp` (Funcion statica que recoge Valor de ventana)

```
void TareaView::recogerValor(QString v, TareaView &tv){
    //funciones especiales correo equipo produccion.
    if(v==""){
        g_s->msgError("Nada seleccionado, se envia normal");
        tv.avisarAsignado();
    }
    if(v=="0"){
        g_s->msgError("Madera");

    }
    if(v=="1"){
        g_s->msgError("Metaclilato");

    }
    if(v=="2"){
        g_s->msgError("Ambos");

    }
}
```

Comment: Para llamar funciones no estáticas necesitas una instancia de objeto.

Comment: Eso tengo entendido pero no lo consigo..

Comment: Has definido `recogerValor` como `recogerValor(QString, TareaView&)` (recibe una referencia) y la has declarado como `recogerValor(QString, TareaView)` (recibe una instancia). La definición y la declaración debe coincidir.

Comment: Pues instancias un objeto `TareaView` y... se lo pasas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++ las funciones que pueden ser llamadas sin una instancia de objeto son conocidas como funciones estáticas... dado que "*estática*" no hace referencia a movimiento si no a su independencia, las funciones que sólo pueden ser llamadas con una instancia de objeto son conocidas como funciones miembro (no se llaman funciones dinámicas).

Las funciones miembro reciben un "*parámetro oculto*" que es el puntero `this` del objeto al que pertenecen; usarán este puntero para acceder a los datos internos que posiblemente use la función al ejecutarse; por ejemplo (en tu caso) `m_enviando_email_al_asignado`.

No puedo saber qué necesita tu programa para corregirse por la falta de contexto, pero si cambias tu función estática para recibir una instancia:

```
void TareaView::recogerValor(QString v, TareaView &tv){
//        Instancia a la que se avisa la asignación --> ~~~
    if(v==""){
        g_s->msgError("Nada seleccionado");
        tv.avisarAsignado(); // <--- Llamada a función miembro.
    }
    if(v=="0"){
        g_s->msgError("Madera");
    }
    if(v=="1"){
        g_s->msgError("Metaclilato");
    }
    if(v=="2"){
        g_s->msgError("Ambos");
    }
}
```

Esquivarás el error.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, efectivamente, estaba instanciando mal, finalmente, en la accion del boton aceptar, he creado la instancia y luego pasado el valor a la funcion "recogerValor".

```
--------------------------------------------------------
TareaViewEquipo.cpp

void TareaViewEquipo::on_mui_aceptar_clicked()
{
    QString valor;
    TareaView *tv;                      <--------- ESTO
    valor=pasarvalor();
    TareaView::recogerValor(QString(valor),tv);  <-- Pasar bien la instancia
    close();
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TareaView.cpp

void TareaView::recogerValor(QString v, TareaView *tv){
    //funciones especiales correo equipo produccion.
    if(v==""){
        g_s->msgError("Nada seleccionado, se envia normal");
        tv->avisarAsignado();
    }

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Hola, se me presenta un problema ahora, las funciones miembro que llamo desde la funcion estatica a traves de la instancia tv, no son capaces de recuperarme el valor de los diferentes argumentos de las funciones, el programa se cierra y en QT aparece The program has unexpectedly finished. Supongo que es porque la instancia que he creado no tiene padre o no coge las referencias del padre cuando se abrió la ventana. Como podría solucionar esto? cuando creo al instancia, pasando le los datos? O como se realizaría? Gracias

Comment: Es normal que te falle ¡estás pasando un puntero vacío!. Yo te sugerí **pasar una referencia**.

Comment: Lo intente con referencia y no me salia :( :( :( que tonto soy, como podria modificarlo por referencia?  muchisimas gracias y siento ser tan lerdo

Comment: error: ‘tv’ declared as reference but not initialized
     TareaView &tv;
                ^

Comment: `TareaView tv; recogerValor("", tv);`

Comment: `TareaView` carece de constructor por defecto, así que no puede ser construido así `TareaView tv;`. Me temo que no puedo ayudarte más porque a) tu problema no es este código si no un desconocimiento más profundo del lenguaje. b) carezco del contexto suficiente de tu programa. c) la sección de comentarios no es el lugar adecuado para debatir sobre un problema de tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo entiendo, gracias.